# Clean URL on localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I'm trying to achieve clean URLs on my localhost (so when I write localhost/contact, it redirects me to localhost/contact.php), but it's not working. I did it according to the older tutorial I found on YouTube, but I probably didn't understand well some parts. Many thanks for every answer. Here is my code:

.htaccess // I am sure I have mod_rewrite allowed.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.so>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /www/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

Script in index.php

```
 include_once('classes/simpleUrl.php');
 $url = new simpleUrl('localhost');
 $test = $url->segment(1);
if (!$url->segment(1)) {
    $page = 'home';
}

else {  
    $page = $url->segment(1);
}

switch ($page) {
    case 'home' :
            echo 'Home page';
            break;
    case 'contact':
        echo 'Contacts page';
        break;
    default:
        echo '404';
        break;  
}
```

classes/simpleUrl.php

```
class simpleUrl {
    var $site_path;



    function __toString() {
        return $this->site_path;
    }

    private function removeSlash($string) {
        if ($string[strlen($string) - 1] == '/') {
            $string = rtrim($string, '/');

        return $string;
        }
    }

    function __construct($site_path) {
        $this->site_path = $this->removeSlash($site_path);
    }

    function segment($segment) {
        $url = str_replace($this->site_path, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        if(isset($url[$segment])) {return $url[$segment];} else {return false;}
        return $url;
    }
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to explain in detail what you mean by "not working". Is there an error/warning you could show?

Comment: also, from what I see in your sample code, you seems to be printing out "Home Page","Contacts page" instead of actually redirectly to contact.php. Is this the actual code you are running?

Comment: Yes, this echo is temporary solution, to see if it's working, later I will use include function. It gives me basic error "/url" was not found on this server when I type localhost/url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$url = new simpleUrl('localhost');` 
`localhost` is not shown in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` so in this case you may simply use `$url = new simpleUrl('index.php');`

**OR**

Use this code for `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

because when you do this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Your actual URL may become something like this:

```
localhost/index.php/contact
```

So it's better requested URL to stay same.

but in this case use:

```
$url = new simpleUrl('');
```

**Oho, look at this mistery:**

```
private function removeSlash($string) {
    if ($string[strlen($string) - 1] == '/') {
        $string = rtrim($string, '/');

    return $string;
    }
}
```

when passed `$string` does not ends with slash it returns nothing, so have to change it in such:

```
private function removeSlash($string) {
    if ($string[strlen($string) - 1] == '/') {
        $string = rtrim($string, '/');
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Now I'll explain when and why to use `$site_path` for `simpleUrl` constructor:
if you have running your script in subdirectory, for ex: if you are working under /www/test/ then you should you `test` as param to pass to `simpleUrl` constructor, otherwise leave it blank

**Update 3**

You should change `simpleUrl`s `segment` method to this:

```
function segment($segment) {
    $url = trim(str_replace($this->site_path, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),'/');
    $url = explode('/', $url);
    if(isset($url[$segment])) {return $url[$segment];} else {return false;}
    return $url;
}
```

and next use `0` as index instead of `1` - `$url->segment(0)`

Comment: I tried it, but still when I write localhost/products It gives me error: The requested URL /products was not found on this server instead of products page.

Comment: I've updated answer several times so please check again, and tell me

Comment: Are you sure you have to use this line: `RewriteBase /www/`? try commenting it out and tell me if any changes

Comment: I removed it and followed are your instructions, but no change. When I use $url = new simpleUrl(''), it gives me error:  Notice: Uninitialized string offset: -1 in C:\wamp\www\classes\simpleUrl.php on line 12

Comment: I've updated: there was mistake in `removeSlash` method, also you don't need `RewriteBase /www/` as I said above, I've tested code and it's working.

Comment: Still same error with uninitialized string. Error is somewhere on line:
 if ($string[strlen($string) - 1] == '/') {

Comment: uninitialized string? this is strange. I'll update answer again

Comment: On the other side, it finally recognize the url. When I type localhost/products it shows Products page but with that error too.

Comment: can you post full error text? I mean filename where error has occured, line number etc. I think it's outside of this script

Comment: OK this would happen if you passed empty string (as I suggested above, fo some cases), anyway you can reduce `removeSlash` method's code as following: `return trim($string, '/');` this will solve the problem

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for your time, George :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you wish to use more variables like: www.domain.com/folder-with-website/products/product-name or if you could live with: www.domain.com/folder-with-website/products?id=123

But try this:

**index.php**

```
<?php
   $page = $_GET["page"];
   if(file_exists("pages/{$page}.php")) {
       include("pages/{$page}.php");
   } else if(empty($page)) {
       include("pages/home.php");
   } else {
       echo "This page does not exists";
   }
?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1

Options -Indexes
```

**Link setup**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="Home">Home</a> <!-- Just a page without any variables -->
    </li><li>
        <a href="Products">Products</a> <!-- same as Home -->
    </li><li>
        <a href="Details?id=123">Details about product</a> <!-- Page with a variable / extra information -->
    </li><li>
        <a href="Details?id=123&title=hey">Details about product</a> <!-- Page with more variables -->
    </li>
</ul>
```